# Using ASP.NET WebAPI to return Boolean to be consumed by an Ajax GET request

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-web-api

I have built a WebAPI (using version 2) that returns `HttpResponseMessage`.  I make `AJAX` requests to these WebAPI methods, and the WebAPI returns a `JSON` response.  This is all fine and dandy, but now what I need is a way to make an `AJAX` GET request to a WebAPI method that simply returns a Boolean.  Here's an example of a `GET` request I'm using to get `JSON`:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://server/site/api/BulletinBoard/GetUserMessageHistory?userId=' + userId + '&messageId=' + messageId,
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    crossDomain: true,
    success: function (data) {
          DoSomething();                    
    },
    error: function (x, y, z) {
          alert(x + '\n' + y + '\n' + z);
    }
});
```

What I hope to accomplish is something like (this is pseudo-code):

```
    var hasMessageBeenDisplayed = 
        $.ajax({
              url: 'http://server/site/api/BulletinBoard/GetUserMessageHistory?userId=' + userId + '&messageId=' + messageId,
              type: 'GET',
              dataType: 'json',
              crossDomain: true,
              success: function (data) {
                   DoSomething();                    
              },
              error: function (x, y, z) {
                   alert(x + '\n' + y + '\n' + z);
              }
       });
```

Where `hasMessageBeenDisplayed` would be either `true` or `false` returned by my WebAPI method.  Here's an example of my WebAPI method:

```
[HttpGet]
public HttpResponseMessage GetUserMessageHistory(string userId, int messageId)
{
    var userMessageHistory = (from i in db.UserMessageHistories
                              where i.UserId == userId &&
                              i.MessageId == messageId
                              select new
                              {
                                  UserId = i.UserId,
                                  MessageId = i.MessageId,
                                  LastSeen = i.LastSeen,
                              }).ToList();

    HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, userMessageHistory);
    return response;
}
```

To be able to make an `AJAX` request that expects `true` or `false`, would I still return `HttpResponseMessage` from my WebAPI method?  How can I make an `AJAX` GET request whose method it's calling can return `true` or `false`?

Comment: the `$.ajax()` return the `XMLHttpRequest`, if the webapi return 200 status code, it will execute the `success` event of your call. Since you set the `json` in the ajax call, you are sending the request to webapi with the content-type `application/json` and you will get an output in this format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't simply change as:

```
[HttpGet]
public bool GetUserMessageHistory(string userId, int messageId)
{
    var userMessageHistory = (from i in db.UserMessageHistories
                              where i.UserId == userId &&
                              i.MessageId == messageId
                              select new
                              {
                                  UserId = i.UserId,
                                  MessageId = i.MessageId,
                                  LastSeen = i.LastSeen,
                              }).ToList();


    return userMessageHistory.any();
}
```

Comment: how about `userMessageHistory` ?

Comment: Will this work?  I thought of this but didn't try it because I make an HTTP GET request to my WebAPI method, and the caller expects an HttpResponse, not a .NET Boolean return value.  The dataType defined in the AJAX request can only be json, xml, and a couple others, but certainly not a boolean.

Comment: I mean, if this is true, then how would I construct my AJAX call?  Obviously it wouldn't be a JSON response anymore, right?

Comment: @FelipeOriani it's just to figure out, don't be afraid about the content.

Comment: @Mike Marks I think you are misunderstanding how WebAPI works. WebAPI is smart enough to know that since you have a method in a controller that you are returning an HTTP response. So even when you return primitive types such as int, string, and bool, it will send it out in XML or JSON depending on what you have it configured for. It's that simple.

Comment: @Mike Marks To see what I mean, just create a new WebAPI project and use their default website template. If you look at their code, they are just returning `string` and `string[]`

Comment: @FelipeKM Thank you, I just assumed that the response always needed to be `HttpResponseMessage`.  This works.

Comment: @FelipeKM, you should change the return statement to `return userMessageHistory.Any();`.  I tried to edit it, but my edit was declined.

Comment: @MikeMarks Yep, I posted it just to figure out that it's possible. Anyway, just fixed it thx.

Comment: One point, your HttpResponseMessage has the ability to send HttpStatusCode with it.When you are using simple primitive type, aren't you losing that? Thoughts?